# Cannot boot any Linux distro from USB on Macbook Air running High Sierra

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, macbook

I have attempted to install Linux on my Macbook Air (2014) and it worked fine yesterday running Sierra, but after updating to High Sierra I cannot get a bootable USB to boot. I have used `dd` to create a bootable USB with Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian and Manjaro, and while it was successful yesterday, today it says there is no boot device after attempting to start from the USB. I have tried with different drives, different images but the error still persists and since I haven't changed anything except for updating macOS i am guessing that must be the issue. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: The exact same unchanged USB was booting linux fine yesterday, but today it won't boot? Or you've been playing with new USB's... verify one that works & try it. And were there any bios/system changes from the upgrade that would prevent usb booting?

Comment: @Xen2050 No I used the same unchanged USB as yesterday. At first I assumed it was an issue with the image so I attempted to use a different one, but after that didn't work I switched USB drives in hope of making progress. All I have done is updated macOS to High Sierra and reinstalled refind since it had been disabled by the update.

Comment: Since rEFInd is a boot manager, I'd look hard at it, maybe it's settings are changed or it doesn't like the update for some reason

Comment: I second Xen2050’s suggestion of looking at rEFInd. I’ve booted Linux LiveUSBs since going to High Sierra, but I used the Mac bootROM’s built-in boot picker to do it (hold down <option> at boot, select the icon representing USB drive from the list of bootable volumes)

Comment: Alright, thanks I will look at refind to see if that is causing issues.

Comment: Any update on this, @Aleppi?